# How can I add a delete button to feature forms?

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis, qt

I have created some formulars in QTDesigner for capturing and manipulating data in QGIS. The data is stored in a postgis-database.

It would be helpful to have a delete-button in this formulars to delete the open feature. At the moment my formulars only contain the 'OK' and 'Cancel' Button.

How can I add a 'Delete'-Button?

---

Here my code. It's based on the example in the refered post. The delete() function is the missing part. Can I use something like currentItem,..?

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  

id_flaecheField = None  
id_fotoField = None  
myDialog = None  

def formOpen(dialog,layerid,featureid):  
   global myDialog  
   myDialog = dialog  
   id_fotoField = dialog.findChild(QComboBox,"id_foto")  
   id_flaecheField = dialog.findChild(QComboBox,"id_flaeche")
   buttonDelete= dialog.findChild(QPushButton,"pushButton")
   buttonDelete.clicked.connect(delete)

def delete():
# missing part of the delete function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need some python code to accomplish this. Have a look at [this](http://nathanw.net/2011/09/05/qgis-tips-custom-feature-forms-with-python-logic/) post which explains, how you add custom business-logic to your widgets.

You will have to save the `layerid` and the `featureid` which you get when the form is created and use these for your operation.
Please note, that with this code, the layer has to be manually switched into edit mode. Connecting to the [appropriate signals from QgsVectorLayer](https://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a476eaf6ec8f2a45e285e963bcacedcc2) and toggling the button state accordingly is left as an exercise for the reader ;)

## QGIS 2.0

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

id_flaecheField = None
id_fotoField = None

myDelToolFeature = None
myDelToolLayer = None

def formOpen(dialog,layer,feature):
    global myDelToolFeature
    global myDelToolLayer

    myDelToolFeature = feature
    myDelToolLayer = layer

    id_fotoField = dialog.findChild(QComboBox,"id_foto")
    id_flaecheField = dialog.findChild(QComboBox,"id_flaeche")
    buttonDelete= dialog.findChild(QPushButton,"pushButton")
    buttonDelete.clicked.connect(delete)

def delete():
    # Delete the feature
    myDelToolLayer.deleteFeature( myDelToolFeature.id() )
```

## QGIS 1.8

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  

from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry

id_flaecheField = None
id_fotoField = None

myDelToolFeatureId = None
myDelToolLayer = None

def formOpen(dialog,layerid,featureid):  
    global myDelToolFeatureId
    global myDelToolLayer

    myDelToolFeatureId = featureid
    myDelToolLayer = layerid

    id_fotoField = dialog.findChild(QComboBox,"id_foto")
    id_flaecheField = dialog.findChild(QComboBox,"id_flaeche")
    buttonDelete= dialog.findChild(QPushButton,"pushButton")
    buttonDelete.clicked.connect(delete)

def delete():
    # Get the layer from the registry
    layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer( myDelToolLayer )
    # Delete the feature
    layer.deleteFeature( myDelToolFeatureId )
```

Comment: Thanks! I already found this and thougt it could be the only way to implement the function.So I try my luck with python..

Comment: I've created the delete-button in the widget and have the python code to adress this button. Has anybody a hint for me how to implement the delete-function on the button? (I can't find the correct delete, remove,.. function) Sorry, I'm a absolute beginner in python.

Comment: Please post the code you already have, so it will be easier to focus on the missing parts.

Comment: Can you please add it to your original question. It is really hard to decipher like this :)

Comment: I get a KEY-ERROR at this line: `layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()[myDelToolLayer]`

Comment: Sorry, the argument names featureID and layerID where misleading. They are actually not ids but references provided there. Code is updated.

Comment: I tried and learned a lot, but I'm still not able to fix the errors. With your code I get for `myDelToolLayer.deleteFeature( myDelToolFeature.id() )` the following error: `'str' object has no attribute 'deleteFeature'`. But also the part `myDelToolFeature.id()` is not working: `'int' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: The API has changed between 1.8 and 2.0. Now there is the code for both.